# How to click in the menu with google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I added a button in my google sheet and I assigned a script to it.
I want that if I click the button, my script automatically click one submenu in the default menu (in Add-ons).
How can I do it? I only see tutorial on how to to add a custom menu but not this.

Sorry if it's a silly question, this is my first script ever.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I guess you want to click one submenu in order to fire a function. Why not attaching this function directly to the button?